# Windows 10 - Segmentation fault using the gtkmm-3.0 library and g++ [reproduction included]

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, g++, gtkmm

### Context

I'm not a huge fan of spamming StackOverflow with questions, but I've been trying to get this working for the past two days. Here goes...

I've come up with a small reproduction of a basic C++ file that **compiles** and **runs perfectly** on Linux (ubuntu), but compiles and results in an **immediate SegFault** (or constant access violation that seem to happen on the gtkmm event loop) on Windows 10 using the MSYS2 (mingw64) g++ compiler.

For MSYS2, I'm using the `mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3` package, recommended by the docs. My thoughts are that this is a problem during the linking process? No GUI appears, only terminal errors.

**The line that causes the problem** is specifically `App::App : myLabel("HelloWorld") {`.

*By initialising the list inside the constructor* using `label = Gtk::Label("Hello world!");`, **the program actually works** on Windows 10 as well, although I later found another segfault in another small detail.

I'm quite new to C++, my question is, am I doing something very wrong in my code or is it possible that the gtkmm library just isn't optimized for Windows, or that the binaries are out of date? I imagine that doing a lengthly compilation of the gtkmm source would work? Or am I just making a dumb pointer mistake?

### Reproduction

MSYS2 setup:

```sh
$ pacman -Syu gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```

Compiled with:

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++11 `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` -o app app.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`
```

The sample that segfaults:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/label.h>
#include <string>

// Class prototype
class Window : public Gtk::Window {
  public:
    Window();
    Gtk::Label myLabel;
};

// Entry point, create app and initialise window
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto app(Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "ch.epfl.cemes.marcus.test"));
  Window window;
  return app->run(window);
};

// Extend Gtk::Window and show some text
Window::Window() : myLabel("Hello world!") {  // this line seems to be the problem
  add(myLabel);
  myLabel.show();
};
```

Running the compiled executable of the code above on Windows results in the following error filling up the console repeatedly:

```
Exception code=0xc0000005 flags=0x0 at 0x0000000100401E9C. Access violation - attempting to read data at address 0x0000000021646CC2
```

My main application, that is practically identical but split into more files, exits immediately with the following:

```
Exception code=0xc0000005 flags=0x0 at 0x0000000063F14B9D. Access violation - attempting to read data at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
      0 [main] archipelago 1909 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to archipelago.exe.stackdump
```

and yields a beautiful file with 15 lines of stack frames.

I appreciate the time you took to read this post. Have a great day!

Comment: Just tried it on Ubuntu and I confirm it does not segfault.

Comment: I've heard people that have had better luck with the vcpkg and msvc binaries, but GTKmm just isn't a Windows-first library. I expect this just falls under the category of "very complicated fix, use Qt or native".

Answer (score 0):

Look in https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Label.html
Seems to me their constructor does not offer `char* const` parameter. Use `myLabel.set_text("HelloWorld");` instead.

Comment: That is true. It uses ```glib::ustring```, which does offer a constructor of ```glib::ustring(const char* src)```. I would assume the compiler is able to handle these implicit conversions?

Comment: You are right! My answer is not correct. I tried your code on Linux + valgrind + extra compilation flags and no issue ! Have you the same crash with myLabel.set_text("HelloWorld"); ?

Comment: Just tried it again to confirm with the above sample, `set_text` will also cause an access violation (segfault), without the initialiser list. Removing the `set_text` line (blank label) will show an empty window . Thanks for the help anyway, I was hoping I was missing something obvious. I'll stick to Linux for GTKmm.